# How to get app message from companion app if Pebble app is in background?

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble, pebble-js

"I am explaining whole scenarios here in order to avoid multiple discussion threads, as I am looking for quick help, so providing here all the details."

I have created a application which communicates with the android companion app, which has some of events scheduled and needs to send to pebble app, so that even if the timeline is muted for our app we can provide important information to pebble app user.

I am able to get the data from companion app and process it successfully only if the **pebble app is open** but my one more requirement is :

**To get data in pebble app sent by companion app, even if my pebble app is in background.**

ie. If the companion app sends me some message but the pebble app is in background so I should be able to read that message and wake up the Pebble app to show the desired information.

I am using "**App Message**" for communication between Companion app and Pebble app.

I gone through the Pebble Documentation which states  :

> "Background workers do not have access to the UI APIs, they also cannot use theAppMessage API or load resources. Most other APIs are available includingAccelerometerService, CompassService, DataLogging and Storage."

**One more Query is** :
As we can get notification in our Pebble if its came to Phone, so is there any way to open some desired app or related app to that message in Pebble watch.

Please guide me if there is anyway to get this done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your Android application can launch the watchapp before sending the message to her. That should solve your problem.

As indicated in the documentation, the background worker on the watch cannot receive app messages.